# Covertir consulta SQL a variable Java

Tags: java, sql

La pregunta es sencilla, se realiza una consulta (query) de SQL usando Java, ¿Es posible almacenar el resultado de esta consulta en una variable String de Java?

**¿Cómo se realiza ese proceso?**

En este ejemplo se consulta cual es el tiempo promedio segun la base de datos para elaborar un arreglo de flores X, supongamos que es de 00:07:00 minutos. Lo que quiero es que ese tiempo se almacene en una variable Java de tipo String para su uso posterior dentro del codigo.

`statement.executeQuery("SELECT Tiempo_elaboracion FROM catalogo_arreglos WHERE Id_arreglo='"+id_arre+"'");`

Comment: La respuesta es si. Si se puede almacenar el resultado en cualquier variable.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré el proceso y lo posteo por si alguien necesita ayuda en el futuro.

```
ResultSet myRS;
PreparedStatement miConsulta
//Debajo de esta linea "con" es el nombre mi conexion//
miConsulta= con.prepareStatement(SELECT valor FROM tabla WHERE condicion)
myRS = miConsulta.executeQuery();
//La finalidad de esto es guardar el resultado de la xconsulta en un String llamado tiempo"
if(myRS.next()){
String tiempo = myRS.getString(1);
//La siguiente linea solo imprime el String tiempo para corroborar el proceso//
System.out.println(""+tiempo);
}
```